# What is the probability that one of your customers does not sign up either way?

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

Is my math correct for this question?

> Suppose that $25\%$ of your customers sign up for special offers via email, and $20\%$ of your customers sign
>   up for special offers via regular mail. Moreover, $5\%$ of all your customers sign up for both. What is the
>   probability that one of your customers does not sign up either way?

$1-P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(\text{not }A \cup \text{not }B)$
$1-.25+.2-.05 = .6 = 60\%$

I'm pretty sure it's correct, but the online hw is marking it wrong, could use suggestions if they're wrong.

Comment: Formatting tips here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to remove any ambiguity from your question.

Comment: Some of your notation is wrong, and there are missing parentheses, but other than that it looks fine. What are you inputting into the homework thing? Just the final numerical answer? Did you input ".6" or "60%"? Does it accept percent values, or values between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

There is miscalculation $=1-0.25+0.2-0.05=0.9\neq0.6$

---

Probability of neither $A$ nor $B$ :

$P(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})=1-P\overline{(A\cup B)}$

$=1-(P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B))$

$=1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A\cap B)$

$=1-0.25-0.20+0.05$

$=0.60$

$60\%$ of customers does not sign up either way.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

$1-P(A)+P(B)-P({A}\cap{B})=P(\neg{A}\cup\neg{B})$

This is right:

$1-\color\red(P(A)+P(B)-P({A}\cap{B})\color\red)=P(\neg{A}\cup\neg{B})$

---

Using the right formula would give you $1-(0.25+0.20-0.05)=0.6$.